# python get Object inside Object property by text

Tags: python-3.x, oop, object

i have an object which hold object
Example :

```
class db_foo_mng
    db_user = "test"
    def __init__(self):
        pass

class rdata:
    db_foo = None
    def __init__(self):
        self.db_foo = db_foo_mng()
        pass
```

and i can access it like this with no problem :

```
self.rdata.db_foo.db_user
```

i like to access the db_user part with string so it will be like: they don't work of course

```
self.rdata.db_foo['db_user'] 
or 
self.rdata.db_foo.get('db_user')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a variable which belongs to an instance of the class, then you can use the `__dict__` to access it using the string.

If the variable in question is a `class variable` (like yours) then you can't even use the `__dict__` to get the attributes.

However the vars() method returns the info in a dict. You can probably make use of that. Store that in db_foo.class_variables and use it later.

```
>>> vars(rdata_obj.db_foo.__class__)['db_user']
'test'
>>>
```

Please see the below code for an example.

```
user@user-Inspiron:~/code/general$ cat example.py  
class Contained:
    class_variable = 'This is a class variable'

    def __init__(self):
        self.instance_variable = 'This is an instance variable'

class Container:
    def __init__(self):
        self.contained_class_instance = Contained()
        self.contained_class_variables = vars(self.contained_class_instance.__class__)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    container = Container()
    print(container.contained_class_instance.__dict__['instance_variable'])
    print(container.contained_class_variables['class_variable'])

user@user-Inspiron:~/code/general$   
user@user-Inspiron:~/code/general$  
user@user-Inspiron:~/code/general$ python example.py  
This is an instance variable
This is a class variable
user@user-Inspiron:~/code/general$  
user@user-Inspiron:~/code/general$
```